# CONVERT ASP TO ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Which is the best way to convert a .asp page to .aspx? Classic asp to asp.net.
I'm trying to avoid rewriting all the pages from scratch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a completely different language and you really can't avoid doing everything from scracth. I think that any solution other than starting all over would take just as much time and headache than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on a lot of things.  Mainly, how complicated the page is, and what it does.  You will need to be a little more specific in your question, but there really isn't any single "one shot" solution.

Comment: Some of my pages are simple. Just a table that shows data, but some of them are very complicated. There is no magic tool that will do the work for me?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are many, many differences between ASP and ASP.NET  One example being the separation of the HTML and the actual code of the page.  The easiest thing to do would be to go through each page and make note of everything each does and begin the process of re-coding them.  As far as I know there is no direct asp-asp.net method.  Sorry to bring you the bad news, but it's good to find out early and not waste your time on these sorts of things. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My first shot at asp.net was migrating an asp application and there was and still is no straightforward migration path. The best that we found was so split the application up into functional areas then migrate each area - effectively running two apps with a bridge inbetween.

I always thought that ASP.Net was misnamed as it made it look like an upgrade to classic ASP which really don't believe it is. ASP.Net is more like an attempt to bring windows style programming to the web, abstracting away the stateless nature of the http request - certainly in it's webforms incarnation

If you are determined for a classic ASP style app you could include all the code on one page forgetting the page behind model though that would be unusual. If you can make decisions about the technology used you could consider MVC as conceptually at least it has more in common with ASP than the webforms. MVC admits it's a web app (like ASP) whereas webforms prefer to hide that fact under the covers.

Comment: How do you construct the bridge?  I've got an ASP.Net application and was handed a 3rd party section to dump in that I need to pass data to/from.  No luck making it happen so far.